# roboearth detection of living objects

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this question is very speculative fiction...
Is roboearth designed to handle living objects like cats and dogs ?

Regards,
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11169/roboearth-detection-of-living-objects/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

RoboEarth in itself is a system for exchanging information between robots, for now mainly action descriptions, environment maps, and object recognition models (see roboearth.org). The currently released packages mainly deal with object recognition models and provide tools for creating, up- and downloading models, and for recognizing the objects described by these models.

The recognition models are based on SIFT features, local image feature points that require some texture on the objects to work reliably, and assume non-deformable objects. As cats and dogs are very flexible, recognizing them will hardly work with these methods.

cheers,
Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4